# Text not appearing in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have a listview in which i wanted to have custom typeface e.g. Arial. for this i subclassed the SimpleAdapter and implemented  the the typeface for textviews in the list. But after this implementation, the list appears to be blank but the onClick is still working and clicking on the blank list item navigates me to the next activity as required.

Code

```
public class TopNewsActivity extends ListActivity {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "Infra";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
}

public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TopNewsGroup.group);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... paths) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String xml = XMLfunctions.getTopNewsXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Number of Results: " + numResults);
        if ((numResults <= 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "No Result Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("title", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
            map.put("date", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "date"));
            map.put("recordDate", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "recordDate"));
            mylist.add(map);
        }
        return mylist;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {



        ListAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(TopNewsActivity.this, result, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title", "date" }, new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        final ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, final int position, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(TopNewsActivity.this, NewsDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("content_id", o.get("id"));
                i.putExtra("title", o.get("title"));
                i.putExtra("date", o.get("recordDate"));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                View v = TopNewsGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ShowNews", i).getDecorView();

                // Again, replace the view
                TopNewsGroup.group.replaceView(v);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

        Typeface localTypeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
        View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        tt.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
        tt.setTypeface(localTypeface1);
        tt.setTextColor(android.R.color.black);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle);
        bt.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
        bt.setTypeface(localTypeface1);
        bt.setTextColor(R.color.grey);
        return v;
        /*Typeface localTypeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
        View v = super.getView(position, view, parent);
        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(localTypeface1);
        return v;*/
    }
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is quite simple as it was my mistake, wasn't providing the ItemText to be viewed to the getView method:

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.results = data;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

        Typeface localTypeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
        View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        tt.setText(results.get(position).get("title"));
        tt.setTypeface(localTypeface1);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle);
        bt.setText(results.get(position).get("date"));
        bt.setTypeface(localTypeface1);
        return v;
    }
}
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

In the Declaration of Simple Adapter use this code

```
public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
}
```

Or in other places , Change your ArrayList to List . I feel there's a conflict there .

[Rahul, Use this link to understand a bit more on using SimpleAdapter](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/)

Comment: Vivek: Thanks a ton buddy for your help and time, it was my mistake as i was not providing the text from the list to be displayed to the getView method. 

I've posted the solution

Comment: No problem buddy, Though i really put in 1 hour to solve your issue, But the fact is, I dont know Android application development or coding involved. i just read through a few articles and how things work , And TADA , Solved it :)